# Get class of cloned element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to get the class of a cloned element, if it's possible, here is my script:

```
var numberOfDoc = $("input[type=checkbox]").each( function (index) {
    $(this).addClass("doc" + index);
})

$("input").change( function () {
    if(this.checked) {
        var checked = $(this).parent().find("span");
        $("span.noneAttached").fadeOut('slow', function () {
            checked.clone().appendTo(".attachedDocuments").after("<br />").text();
        });
    }
    else if ($("input:checked").length == 0) {

        $("span.noneAttached").fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```

As you can see, I am giving each checkbox it's own class name based on it's index number.  When a checkbox is clicked, it finds it's parent, then the span, clones it, and appends the text of the span to another div.

Right after the span is cloned, I need to be able to find the class name that the checkbox has been given and add it to the span that is being cloned and appended to keep track of where each span actually came from.

Any thoughts here?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what is the desired result / user experience?

Comment: Basically, someone checks checkboxes and based on the checkboxes that are clicked, files are added to a form that will ultimately be emailed out to someone else.  I need to keep track of which spans are being added from which checkbox to remove them later on an uncheck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(this).attr('class')` to get the class name of the checkbox, assuming `this` references the checkbox.

Also, you can get an array of all of the checked input on a page using `$("input:checked")`.

Comment: Ahh, of course.  I think `.prop()` might be better suited for this though.

Comment: I could see `prop()` being more appropriate if you were going for something like `tagName` or `nodeType`, but you wrote that you wanted the class attribute, and `attr()` is more explicit in that regard.